# CSS - 2 Simple css codes works great separately,When Add together Collapse (Not browser specific)

Tags: html, css, center, css-tables

Two simple codes- 1 with centered table inside a div. And the other is Photo next to Text Inside a DIV -
I played a little bit with the code and I **think** that the Float:Left in the Photo next to Text is the cause (might be).Here is the 2 Fiddles: 1 for each code-block.

1) centered table inside a div -

[First demo](http://jsfiddle.net/V6gv7/)

2) photo next to text in a div (In the fiddle it's below because it's responsive- full screen will show it as next not below -

[Second demo](http://jsfiddle.net/uH63A/)

Code for the photo -

```
<div id="up_div">
<img id="selfie" src="selfie.jpg">
<p id="text" dir="rtl"> tree typically has many secondary branches supported clear of the ground by the trunk...</p>    

</div>

#selfie {
    border:solid;
    border-width: 5px;
    border-color: white;
    webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 1px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.8);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 1px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.8);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 1px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.8);
    float: left;
    max-width: 400px;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 35px 10px 15% 0;
}
```

I can't post three links because of reputation - so please just add to one of the Fiddles the other one and see. Sorry!!

**Note: To see the collapse you have to increase the size of the window - or else it will look fine because it's responses. The problem is in full screen.**

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: When it's a wide screen - the text next to the photo work'ts great.

Comment: @hungerstar but when i add the table below- it's inhale to the left side of the screen and not centring - but if you decrease the screen size a little but it's center himself again. im trying to achieve that dosent matter what is the screen width- it will be below the upper div and be centered- the table i mean.. understand? :9

Comment: No not really. Could you make a simple graphic that would represent the positioning of elements that you are trying to achieve?

Comment: @hungerstar i did ! first Link- Good position(When DECREASE  window size - http://imagizer.imageshack.com/img540/4870/jR0Wpw.png . Second Link- Bad position when INCREASE window size: http://imagizer.imageshack.com/img674/4694/LQWLRx.png                       any suggestions?

Comment: Try using `clear: left` on your `#cont` DIV. http://jsfiddle.net/uH63A/2/

Comment: @hungerstar solved ! thank you man ! how can i vote you?!

Answer (score 0):

Add `display:block;` to your div element,in your case it is #up_div, in the second example of JS Fiddel. 
And then specify the height and width of that #up_div.
Now the text wont distort when you zoom in or out of the page.
See the [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/uH63A/1/)

Comment: the text is not distorting any way. What's disturbing me is that when i'm at full screen or a little bit less of full screen, the TABLE below inhale to the left side of the screen..And i need it centred all the way - Good -  imagizer.imageshack.com/img540/4870/jR0Wpw.png BAD - imagizer.imageshack.com/img674/4694/LQWLRx.png

Comment: Oh! I am sorry I didnt understand what you were trying to say.So what you want is that if you zoom in or out of the page the table remain at its own place and doesnt move?

Comment: Check this out [Demo] (http://jsfiddle.net/uH63A/4/) the table doesnt move when you zoom in or out.Is that what you want?

Comment: Thank you man ! but @hungerstar solved it . i should use clear:left and it's done ! :) thank you anyway !

Answer (score 0):

Try using clear: left on your #cont DIV.

**CSS**

```
#cont {
    clear: left;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/uH63A/2